# Concurrent Test for Apex Request Service

Tags: unit-test

There are two active Portal users in salesforce Considered User 1 and User2
The Following Code:

```
RestRequest req100 = new RestRequest(); 
        req100.requestURI='https://cs81.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/ProfileService/';
        req100.httpMethod = 'post';
        string jsonreq100 = '{"UserId":""}';   
        system.debug(jsonreq100);
        Blob blbVal100 = Blob.valueof(jsonreq100);
           req100.requestbody = blbVal100;
           RestContext.request = req100;
           BusinessProfile1.dopost();
    }
```

The above Code Have to Run Two Users at Same time Using System.RunAs() Method?
Same Request Is it Possible? If it Possible How? Can You Please Explain Anyone Of Them?

Comment: I don't think it possible to run as two user same time. But you can try two methods if can you share your actual requirement then we will able to provide suitable solution.

Comment: If I Share Two Methods,Two Types of Request we Have to  Give that Means Req101 Like That,I want Same Request

Comment: Without Using System.Run As() Method , Is There Any Possible With Another Way

Comment: Are you trying to do some kind of concurrency testing?  If so, you'll want to use an external tool like JMeter:  http://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: Yes For Testing I want ,Because this Condtion for Failing test Input Data

Comment: You might get more responses if you [edit] your post's title and change to: "How to test concurrent requests of an Apex REST Service"